# emmake and emconfigure command not found (osx)

Tags: c, cmake, emscripten, emmake

I'm trying to use CMake with Emscripten. I followed [this official tutorial](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#sdk-download-and-install), cloned the repo with:

```
git clone https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk.git
```

I did:

```
./emsdk install latest
./emsdk activate latest
```

and in general, `emcc` seems to be working. Now I moved on to [this tutorial](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html) and it tells me to use:

```
./emconfigure ./configure
./emmake make
```

Unfortuantely, it doesn't seem like `emconfigure` or `emmake` are anywhere on my `PATH`. I also cannot find them in `emsdk` repo that I cloned earlier. Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the last step in the [Installation Instructions](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#installation-instructions) tutorial you linked (bolded below):

```
# Fetch the latest version of the emsdk (not needed the first time you clone)
git pull

# Download and install the latest SDK tools.
./emsdk install latest

# Make the "latest" SDK "active" for the current user. (writes .emscripten file)
./emsdk activate latest

# Activate PATH and other environment variables in the current terminal
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

This should allow `emconfigure` and `emmake` to be recognized in the current Terminal session.

Comment: After rename "MakeFile" to "makefile" I was able to make